# Show complete request info before yield

Tags: python, scrapy

I am yielding a request that is redirected to another page, which tells me there is something wrong with the request I'm making. From my code it looks good so I want to check the request before it is send.

I was hoping I could just use a debug logger to show me response, but this only shows me:

```
self.logger.debug('Request: %s', req) # req = FormRequest

2017-01-03 11:01:17 [spider] DEBUG: Request: <POST https://website.com>
```

While I'd also like to see the cookies, headers and data that are being submitted with this request.

So ideally I'd like to know how to view the entire request with just one function / variable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default string representation only includes the method and the URL ([source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py#L76)). You could use the [`request_to_dict`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/reqser.py#L10) util function and format the output in any way you like it:

```
def log_request(req):
    self.logger.debug('url: {url}, body: {body}, cookies: {cookies}, headers: {headers}'.format(
        **request_to_dict(req)
    ))
```

(or just log the entire dict, of course)

There is also the [`COOKIES_DEBUG`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:setting-COOKIES_DEBUG) setting, if set to `True` it will log all the received and sent cookies.